# Handle missing data for a dataframe column of datatype object

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe and one of the column is of datatype object . There is a blank element present in this column, so I tried to check if there are other empty element in this column by using `df['colname'].isnull().sum()` but it is giving me `0`. How can I replace the above value(empty) with some arbitrary value(numeric) so that I can convert this column into a column of float datatype for further computation.

Comment: df['colname'].eq(' ').sum()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `pandas.to_numeric`

```
df['colname'] = pd.to_numeric(df['colname'], errors='coerce')
```

This will produce `np.nan` for any thing it can't convert to a number.  After this, you can fill in with any value you'd like with `fillna`

```
df['colname'] = df['colname'].fillna(0)
```

All in one go

```
df['colname'] = pd.to_numeric(df['colname'], errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```